# Why did I lose the Woot! (Enthusiast) Badge?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, activity-badges

A few days ago my OpenID was merged with another OpenID I had. Before the merge I had the [`Woot!` badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/enthusiast) (now called Enthusiast), and now I no longer have it.

I would like to know why it was removed?

Comment: You haven't been as ... *enthusiastic* ... as required, according to our stalking team in the white van outside your workplace.  Please show a little more exuberance when you visit the site each day, mmmkay?

Comment: Did you try looking under the couch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, this was an issue with your accounts being merged - a fix for the merge process will be deployed tonight.

Your user history data has been restored and the "Enthusiast" badge will be awarded when our badge task runs again.

Answer (score 2):

The `Woot!` badge was only called that [during the period of its introduction](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/). Now it's called the `Enthusiast` badge. [It looks like you lost that badge during the merge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34512/why-did-i-lose-the-woot-enthusiast-badge/34541#34541).

Also, badges are *rarely* removed once gained.

You ought to email the Stack Overflow team at **team@stackoverflow.com** with your OpenID and they can take a look for you.

Comment: Why not check that yourself? :) He doesn't, just checked.

Comment: I dont complain about the "woot!" that is removed, but about the badge itself that is removed.. I don't even have the Enthusiast, which I had. And it looks exactly like what you suggested that happended. I'll send the mail.

Comment: @gs I hadn't checked because in his OP that I edited, he said his Stack Overflow OpenID was the same as meta. I thought since he said that that he hadn't merged his accounts.

Comment: Yep, just checked it too.. I thought it could have been the renaming but something happened in the merge.